# Rasterize stuck in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have QGIS 2.18.15 and I'm trying to make a raster layer from polylines or points.
every time I start the process, it looks like it's working but won't really do anything (the cursor turns to round loading cursor, not seen in print screen)
left it all night to raster a single point
it seems like an ordinary problem but yet I couldn't find a solution

the software itself is ok and if I press "cancel" everything ok,
its seems like I'm missing something

[image: image of the rasterize tool]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be your user name. I've had problems with file paths where special characters existed. So my tip would be to copy your data and output file where there are no special characters.